# How to solve " ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax" TypeOrm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

Im getting the error below at my entity.

Full error:

```
 [Nest] 8844  - 09/16/2022, 6:04:23 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)...
[0] QueryFailedError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'array NOT NULL, `enabled` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `credentials` text NULL CO' at line 1  
[0]     at new QueryFailedError (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
[0]     at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\typeorm\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.js:170:45)
[0]     at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
[0]     at Query._callback (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
[0]     at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
[0]     at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:92:8)
[0]     at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
[0]     at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
[0]     at Parser.write (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
[0]     at Protocol.write (C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\\api_DEV\api_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
```

Main error part:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'array NOT NULL, `enabled` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`credentials` text NULL CO' at line 1
```

My entity:

```
@Entity({name: 'webhook'})
export class WebhookEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({nullable: false})
    callbackUrl: string;

    @Column("text",{nullable: false, array: true})
    events: DeliveryStatus[];

    @Column({nullable: false, default: false})
    enabled: boolean;

    @Column('simple-json',{
        nullable: true,
        comment: '{ username: string, password: string}'
    })
    credentials: Credentials;
}
```

I have tried different syntaxs, but still confused how to solve this error.
If anyone have some ideas please share it to me. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have array type. So to store an object or an array of objects you'll have to use JSON type. Moreover the `array: true` property in `@Column` options is only supported for postgresql it seems (https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/typeorm-add-columns-with-array-data-type/)

Comment: Try removing the `array` property and set the column's type to json to see if it works. I'm missing the context for `DeliveryStatus` but I'm curious why it must be a column in the table and not a table itself? Querying JSON columns is relatively more complex in relational dbs but it depends on use case